# Loading views dynamically in codeigniter using an ID

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on a project where a user can upload the files he uses for frontend web development and showing how the work done by him looks in the browser.
In order to do this I am asking the user to upload the project with the html file named test.html.
I am using codeigniter for the purpose.

I have completed the upload process and writing the information in tables but I am stuck in how to provide the link when the file has finished uploading...i.e. I have an upload controller as following:

```
<?php class Main extends CI_Controller { 
  //{construct and all the parts} 
//upload function
function site_pages(){
 $this->load->view('header'); $this->load->view('nav'); $this->load->view('test.html');
      }
function do_upload(){
  .....code for file upload....
...update the database with the folder_id...
 }
```

However after this is done, I need to provide the link to the user i.e. of the form

```
   <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>/main/site_pages/folder_id/test.html" >
```

I am stuck at how to generate this id in this form and how I can load the test.html file in a specific view in the controller

Answer (score 1):

You can Build a controller for this purpose and use that controller to read the uploaded html files. Once you read the file you can output it from within controller

You can map the file name to an id and use this id to identify each file. you can rename the html file from form.html to 2335332.html and later use this id as parameter for reading the file from the directory.

Here is how you can read files.

```
// segment 3 will have parameter passed: 2335332
$file_name=$this->uri->segment(3)."html";

// you should check in this point weather this file exists.

$this->load->helper(‘file’);

//read a file
$data = read_file('./path_to/to/'.$file_name.'.html');
// do javascript/php/other cleanup on $data
```

At this point you have html code and you can output it

```
$this->output->set_output($data);
```

But i should warn you that you should clean the uploaded html files for possible javascript / php code as the user can exploid you system.

Good Luck.

**Edit**

I think you can figure this out but just to let you know, you provide the user with the link as follows

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>user/site_pages/2335332">Link to your page</a>
```

Assuming that your code is inside site_pages() function of the controller: user.

Comment: I got what you are saying butwhat I want is to load multiple html pages that have ben uploaded using a single controller. for this I need to pass a parameter in the form of id to the controller and it will load the html page corresponding to it.....I guess I need a remap..